# JMeter - mark used records on CSV driven test

Tags: csv, jmeter

Using CSV Data Set Config in JMeter works, but sometimes test stop in the middle

Now there are used records in CSV and if we re-run test it'll executed also used records

How can used records not be used in next run?

Theoretically I can write to CSV every usage, but it seems very IO consuming while running test

Is there a solution to mark used CSV records or able to execute only unused records next test run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the "normal" [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) it is not possible, the solutions are in:

1. Use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property you will be able to write down "used" variables into JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles), this way you will know which variables have already been processed. If you want to write them into a separate file - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/). Once test stops abnormally you can use a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) tool to distinguish "used" and "not-used" data
2. Another option is going for [HTTP Simple Table](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) server, it is possible to invoke [`READ` endpoint](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) providing `KEEP=FALSE` parameter, this way "used" records will be removed from the CSV file. This approach also enables re-using the same CSV file in [Distributed Testing mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) without having to copy the CSV file to all slaves and collect used entries from them, also it protects from splitting the CSV file and using duplicate values in the test